# How to defining id to a select tag in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.3

My cakephp code for making a select tag is

```
<?php echo $this->Form->select('User.country_id',array($countries),null,array('id'=>'selection','empty'=>null,'label'=>false,'style'=>'width:231px'));?>
```

Here I defined id='selection' but when I inspect this dropdown box in browser it is showing id='UserCountryId'. How is that happening? My jquery and javascript is not working because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u need Id use cake php syntax

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('User.country_id', array(
    'type'=>'select, 
    'id'=>'selection',
    'style'=>'width:231px'
));
?>
```

your  jquery and javascript will work try this

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('User.country_id', array(
        'type'=>'select,
        'options'=>array($countries), // this is probably not needed 
        'id'=>'selection',
        'empty'=>null,
        'label'=>false,
        'style'=>'width:231px'
    ));
?>
```

Comment: the select dropdown is showing id='UserCountryId' instead of 'selection'. How is that?

Comment: I've tested this on my machine with CakePHP 2.4.6. Are you sure you are changing the right View (add.ctp v/s edit.ctp) ?

Comment: But sice it was not working i changed my jquery and javascript so it doesn't matter now...

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
<?php 

echo $this->Form->input('User.country_id',array('type'=>'select','options'=>$countries,'id'=>'selection'));

?>
```